# Remove a node from graph using NetworkX without copying

Tags: python, networkx

I was wondering if it's possible to remove a node from the graph without modifying the original graph to check if removing that node increase the connected components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a subgraph view without that node.
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html